# How to construct log receiver in Java?

Tags: java, log4j, jms, appender

I'd like to create a `Receiver` to gather and manage logs send by JMSAppender. Now it works only 30 seconds (`Thread.sleep(30000);`), but I need it to be waiting for all logs from system. How can I do this if I need to close `pw.close();` to see all logs in file? From file I load my logs to log viewer and I'd like to see them in real time.

```
public class Receiver implements MessageListener {

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("result.log");

    public Receiver() throws Exception {


        ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
        Connection conn = factory.createConnection();
        Session sess = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        conn.start();
        MessageConsumer consumer = sess.createConsumer(sess.createTopic("logTopic"));
        consumer.setMessageListener(this);

        Thread.sleep(30000);
        consumer.close();
        sess.close();
        conn.close();
        pw.close();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Receiver();

    }

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            LoggingEvent event = (LoggingEvent) ((ActiveMQObjectMessage) message).getObject();

            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"); 
            String nowAsString = df.format(new Date(event.getTimeStamp())); 

            System.out.println("zapisujemy do pliku");
            pw.println("["+ nowAsString + "]" + 
                    " [" + event.getThreadName()+"]" +
                    " ["+ event.getLoggerName() + "]" +
                    " ["+ event.getMessage()+"]");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @HotLicks `JMS Topic` is created by JMSAppender, my question is more about how to process logs in real time if I have to wait for all logs to close file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've written receiver:

```
public class Receiver implements MessageListener {

    static Connection conn;
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory;
    static Session sess;
    static MessageConsumer consumer;


    public Receiver() throws Exception {

        /*
         *  create a logTopic topic consumer
         */
        factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
        conn = factory.createConnection();
        sess = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        conn.start();
        consumer = sess.createConsumer(sess.createTopic("logTopic"));
        consumer.setMessageListener(this);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new ShutDownListener(consumer, sess, conn)));
        new Receiver();
    }


    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            LoggingEvent event = (LoggingEvent) ((ActiveMQObjectMessage) message)
                    .getObject();

            /*
             * log on console and into a file
             */

            FileReceiver.logToFile(event);
            StdoutReceiver.logOnConsole(event);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

With FileReceiver:

```
public class FileReceiver {

    static PrintWriter pw;
    static DateFormat df;

    static {
        try {
            df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS");
            pw = new PrintWriter("result.log");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                pw.close();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void logToFile(LoggingEvent event) {
        String nowAsString = df.format(new Date(event.getTimeStamp()));

        pw.println("[" + nowAsString + "]" + " [" + event.getThreadName() + "]"
                + " [" + event.getLoggerName() + "]" + " ["
                + event.getMessage() + "]");
        pw.flush();


    }
}
```

and StdOutReceiver

```
public class StdoutReceiver {

    public static void logOnConsole(LoggingEvent event) {

        System.out.println("[" + event.getTimeStamp() + "]" + " ["
                + event.getThreadName() + "]" + " [" + event.getLoggerName()
                + "]" + " [" + event.getMessage() + "]");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not close the print writer in constructor and remove your `Thread.sleep()`. Your program will not terminate because you are calling `conn.start();` that creates waiting thread into the JMS client.

Add `pw.flush();` after `pw.println()` into `onMessage()`

EDIT:
you do not have to close file. But if you want to create clean implementation do it in shutdown hook.

Comment: Ok, and what about `consumer.close(); sess.close(); conn.close(); System.exit(1);`? Should I remove it too?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you close it after those 30 secondes, and then even exit the jvm.

Do the closing on JVM exit: [`Runtime.addShutdownHook`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable :) And what about closing file? When should I close my file to save it after each log? It is necessary for log viewer

Comment: Sorry didn't check link. Fixed now. I see you found a better way. Congrats.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'm pointing out the obvious here, but you do realise that you are waiting for 30 seconds **in your constructor**?

If you want to close the connection after 30 seconds, then I would recommend using [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and doing a threadsafe close of the connection there.

A consequence of pausing in your constructor is that when other threads call `onMessage`, your object hasn't finished being created yet and could behave erratically.

Comment: Ok, I see now. But, to justify myself I was using [this tutorial](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j-jms-appender-with-activemq.html) to do this. I didn't notice that is the stupidest thing to remove logging but leaving `Thread.sleep()`

Comment: OMG, the author of that tutorial should be shot!